# Improve experience when using anchor link from different touchpoints

Tags: mobile-application, scrolling

My detail page on mobile app is setting with different sections and have a tab menu fixed on top when scrolling. The issue that I have right now is, each section can be a separate touchpoint on other pages and using anchor link to access respective section when selecting.

For instance: I have 4 section A B C D and touchpoint A on page 1, touchpoint B on page 2.

I cannot predict the order of selecting touchpoint, it could be A first or could be B first. Then how to make sure the experience of user will be smooth if they don't select the A section first. Should using a smooth scrolling effect to section B will be a good option or switch the tab menu B A according to the order of selecting of user first?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or mockup to illustrate the problem? I think the question requires a bit more context about the users and use cases to help come up with suitable solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The design strategy for having fixed positioning of interface menu items is to improve learnability or memorability for the user when navigating the contents.

Usually it is difficult to continue adapting the interface to user activities, because over time they will develop a pattern of usage, but at times they will also deviate from that pattern or behaviour. This is why in general having fixed positions is better overall, unless there is a good reason or use case for it.

Comment: That's true. We already thought about both behaviours and waving pros and cons here. So far we couldn't find a similar approach.